Slowest possible rate for $a_n$ to grow such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n2^{-a_n}=0$
Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a strictly positive non-decreasing sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$. Is it true that for any such $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}n2^{-a_n}=0$? If not, what is the slowest possible rate for $a_n$ to grow such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n2^{-a_n}=0$?

Please detail your efforts towards the problem.

What do you mean, "slowest?" There usually isn't a good definition for such problems, unfortunately.

If $b_n=\frac{a_n}{\log_2 n},$ then $n2^{-a_n}=n^{1-b_n}.$ So you need $\liminf b_n>1.$ The means that there must be an $\alpha>1$ such that $a_n>\alpha \log_2n$ for all but finitely many $n.$

But there might be borderline cases where $\liminf b_n=1,$ where it still converges.

That is perfect thank you Thomas. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.
